# How to programmatically print to CUPS server from Android Things without UI?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, cups, android-things

I have two components in my project:

- One Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie, being used as a [CUPS](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html) print server for a single attached printer.
- One Raspberry Pi 3 running Android Things.  Has a connected screen, but no touch screen.

I'd like to send photos from my Android Things device to my printer.  The problem is that all the [Android Framework APIs for printing](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) involve going through Android's printing UI (which would require touch screen).  So I need a *programmatic* way to send the photo to the printer via CUPS.  Both would be on the same network.  Is there a way to send a photo to an IPP URL using an HTTP POST request?  Or a better way I haven't found yet?

Comment: Some time ago I was involved in a project with customized Android (not Things) where no system UI were allowed, so no printing API. We successfully integrated CUPS and sent byte buffers to a printer... As you understand, it doesn't matter where a byte array comes from (a photo or smth else). Can the same approach be applied to your case? Can you send byte buffers to the server?...